# Careers Profile Completeness Score Recommendation Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I view my profile on Stack Overflow Careers, it says that I have a 207/210 score.  It also tells me that I should tag my projects to improve my profile:

[image: Profile Page Score]

I tagged all I could tag and I still couldn't get those remaining 3 points for a perfect score.

When I click the "View completeness report" link thought, it give me a different recommendation of entering more responsibilites for those points.

[image: Completeness Score Page]

I would think the site would give you the correct incompleteness information on the profile page.

Comment: This has been affecting me for months...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CV edit page now shows actual next steps that need doing to increase the completeness score.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the fix!